# Hook useTranslation() don't read imported namespaces - i18next

Tags: reactjs, namespaces, internationalization, react-hooks, i18next

I'm importing jsons with translations in my React project so I can organize my code. But the useTranslation() hook doesn't seem to read these imported namespaces.

An example of how I'm doing that:

i18n.js:

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
import {
  file1, 
  file2
} from 'translations';

i18next.init({
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false
  },
  lng: 'en',
  resources: {
    en: {
      file1: file1,
      file2: file 2
}
export default i18next;
```

Using useTanslator():

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

export function MyComponent() {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return
   <p>{t('file1:text')}</p>
   <p>{t('file2:file2.text')}</p>
}
```

It shows:

text

file2.text

Edit: I had add the namespaces like useTranslation("file1") but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the namespaces when you call the hook. It should be:

```
useTranslation(["file1", "file2"])
```

Comment: I did that, still don't translate.

Comment: Use the namespace if you've imported multiple namespaces as: `['file1', 'file2']`
For example, file1 is used to be a default namespace but because you've imported 2 namespaces you'll need to use `file2` prefix for those translation keys.

Example: `file2:translationKey`

Answer (score 1):

You need to double check initialization parameters in i18n.js file. You should specify namespace separator (nsSeparator).The rest should follow official documentation.

```
.init({
...........
 resources,
 ns: ['file1', 'file2'],
 defaultNS: 'file1',
 nsSeparator: ':'
..............
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need useTranslation hook with all namespaces on component (first ns is default). Just add all namespace which you want use to array inside useTranslation hook.

```
const { t } = useTranslation(["file1", "file2"]);
```

I edit your code

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

export function MyComponent() {
  const { t } = useTranslation(["file1", "file2"]);

  return
   <p>{t('text')}</p> //or you can use t('text', {ns: "file1"})
   <p>{t('file2.text', {ns: "file2"})}</p>
}
```

ns options is recomended for namespaces

Comment: Is there anything that can check for this? maybe an eslint plugin or something?

Comment: I think, there is no tool to check this. It's not in their documentation and it depends on library implementation.